# Is it possible to use MockMvc without SpringJUnit4ClassRunner?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I want to use MockMvc without SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     WebApplicationContext wac = ...;
     MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
   }
```

Since  main is not invoked by a springcontainer how do I create a WebApplicationContext?

Is something like the following not-working pseudocode possible?

```
 WebApplicationContext wac = new WebApplicationContext("classpath./service-context.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways to create a `MockMvc` instance:

1. From a `WebApplicationContext`, loaded either via the *Spring TestContext Framework* (e.g., using `@ContextConfiguration` and `@WebAppConfiguration`) or manually.
2. In stand-alone mode using a `@Controller` class.

Both of these are documented in the [Setup Options](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-setup-options) section in the *Testing* chapter of the reference manual.

To create a `WebApplicationContext` *manually*, instantiate a `GenericWebApplicationContext` and load the bean definitions from XML files like this:

```
GenericWebApplicationContext context = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context).loadBeanDefinitions(/* XML config files */);
context.refresh();
```

Or from `@Configuration` classes like this:

```
GenericWebApplicationContext context = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
new AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader(context).register(/* @Configuration classes */);
context.refresh();
```

Note that you'll want to configure and set a `MockServletContext` in the `context` as well.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)